# Switching Go version when process.env["GOROOT"] is set is unsupported

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, environment

I am using M2, and use brew installed go 1.20. Now I want to switch Go version in VSCode:

[image: Choose Go Environment in VSCode]

But it failed with this warning message:

```
Switching Go version when process.env["GOROOT"] is set is unsupported.
```

[image: warning message]

After removing `GOROOT` from `.zshrc`, `GOROOT` has been disapeared from `env`. But it still exist in `go env`. How can I remove `GOROOT` from `go env`? I also tried to remove it from `${HOME}/Library/Application Support/go/env`, but I still can not switch Go version.

```bash
➜  ~ env |grep GOROOT
➜  ~ go env GOROOT
/usr/local/go
```

Comment: How do you switch go version? Where does this `GOROOT is set` error come from? Does `go env -w GOROOT=""` work for you?

Comment: Do not install Go via brew and do not change versions.

Comment: @ZekeLu go env -w GOROOT="" doesn't work, after do that, I check it in "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/go/env" and shows GOROOT="". but go env still has GOROOT set.  I don't know where GOROOT is set, maybe brew install set it.  Now I have to set "go.goroot" in settings.json to change the go version.

Comment: @ZekeLu  switch go version steps: Use the button bar(which shows go version) at the bottom, then select "Choose Go Environment" in the top windows.

Comment: @Volker It works fine in my working macbook, I usally switch go version in vscode for different go projects .

Comment: @lowang I have uploaded images captured on my computer. But it's not from a macOS. You can edit the answer to replace the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Choose Go Environment** is a feature of the vscode-go extension (see [Managing Your Go Version](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/ui.md#managing-your-go-version)).

If after removing `GOROOT` from `.zshrc`, the output from `env | grep GOROOT` is empty, then you have done the right thing to make the feature work.

Bear in mind that the change won't be observed by VSCode immediately. It's required to restart VSCode. The tricky thing is, if VSCode is started by a process that has `GOROOT` set, VSCode will still see it. So maybe it's better to restart the system to be safe.

---

> Now I have to set "go.goroot" in settings.json to change the go version.

You should remove this configuration after restart VSCode or reboot the system. Otherwise, you will get this warning:

```
Switching Go version when "go.goroot" is set is unsupported.
```

---

> But it still exist in `go env`. How can I remove `GOROOT` from `go env`.

This is expected. You don't need to, and can't, remove it from the output of `go env`.

`go env GOROOT` shows the effective setting of `GOROOT`. It shows the value from one of the following sources (higher priority first):

1. the path inferred from the current `go` command. For example, if you have go1.19 installed with `go install golang.org/dl/go1.19@latest`, running `go1.19 env GOROOT` will give you the path like `$HOME/sdk/go1.19`.
2. the `GOROOT` environment variable;
3. the value set in the Go environment configuration file (`go env GOENV` shows the path to the configuration file).
4. the path inferred from the `go` command found in the `PATH` parts (this is a little confusing compared to point 1 above).

Comment: Yes, it works now after removing `go.root` from settings and restart vscode.

Comment: Hi, @Zeke Lu, I also met the issue that "Choose go environmen" does not take effect. It still the go version which is at /usr/local/bin/go. /usr/local/bin/go is the link to go installed via brew. Although I have changed the link /usr/local/bin/go to point to anothe go bin, it still does not take effect use "choose go environment" in vscode after reload vscode.

Comment: Hi @lowang, I think your use case is to select a special go version for a special project. In this case, I think it's better to add `"go.goroot": "/path/to/the/special/go/root"` to the `.vscode/settings.json` file. You can find the `GOROOT` for the go version you want with this command: `go1.17.11 env GOROOT` (assumes that you want to find `GOROOT` for `go1.17.11`).

Comment: If it does not work, please provide the steps guide about how to reproduce the issue.