# Older go version not working run and debug Delve

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I have multiple go versions installed, 1.20.5 and 1.17.9

I am using Go 1.17.9 for this project as when I run `go version` I get `go version go1.17.9 linux/amd64`

Using run and debug in delve, with my launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        }
    ]
}
```

I get:
"Version of Delve is too old for Go version 1.20.5 (maximum supported version 1.18, suppress this error with --check-go-version=false)"

How can I make it so that Go version 1.17.9 is used in Run and Debug?

Answer (score 0):

You can [Choose Go Environment](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/ui.md#managing-your-go-version) in vs-code to choose another version of Go. See the screenshot below:

[image: Choose Go Environment]

See also [Switching Go version when process.env["GOROOT"] is set is unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76306692/switching-go-version-when-process-envgoroot-is-set-is-unsupported) if you failed to switch to another version of Go.

Answer (score 0):

you can add customize args to delve in `$(pwd)/.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "go.delveConfig": {
    "dlvFlags": [
      "--check-go-version=false"
    ]
  },
}
```